# C++ Socket Send to Java Server gets hanged after some hours

Tags: java, c++, sockets, tcpsocket

My C++ program which is the client connects with the Java server . From the time of connection establishment the C++ client sends a block of data of size ~1MB to 3MB in a fixed frequency( say 10 sec).

My Java server opens a socket

```
Socket client = new ServerSocket(14001, 10).accept();//blocking
ReceiveThread st = new ReceiveThread(client);
```

and it receives the data from client as below.

```
private String getDataFromSocket(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException
    {
        int byteLimit = 1024*1024*2; //2 MB
        String output = "";
        char[] charArray = null;

        int availableSize = is.available();
        if(availableSize < 1)          // If available size is 0 just return empty
        {
            return output;
        }
        while(availableSize > byteLimit)   // Reads 2MB max if available size is more than 2 MB
        {
            charArray = new char[byteLimit];
            reader.read(charArray,0,charArray.length);
            output += new String(charArray);
            availableSize = is.available();
        }
        charArray = new char[availableSize];
        reader.read(charArray,0,charArray.length);
        output = output +new String(charArray);
        return output;
    }
```

The above GetDataFromSocket keeps on checking for available data till the socket is closed gracefully.

the C++ connects with the Java server

```
void CreateSocket()
{
    int  err, nRet = 0;
    sockfd = 0;
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;


    //WSACleanup();// Is this needed?
    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(1, 1);

    while (1)
    {
        err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);

        if (err != 0)
        {
            Sleep(50);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    while (1)
    {
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd == -1 || sockfd == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            Sleep(50);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            nRet = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void ConnectWithServer()
{
    int nRet = 0;   
    char myname[256] = { 0 };
    int wsaErr = 0, portNum = 0, retryCount=0;
    struct hostent *h = NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    gethostname(myname, 256);

    portNum = 1401;

    while (1)
    {
        if ((h = gethostbyname(myname)) != NULL)
        {
            memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));

            memcpy((char *)&server_addr.sin_addr, h->h_addr, h->h_length);

            server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNum);
            server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr*) h->h_addr);
        }

        if (0 == connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)))
        {
            nRet = 1;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
        }
        Sleep(50);
    }
}
```

The connection establishment to the server is done by the above two functions and it returns success. After these steps i am sending the data buffer to the Java server once in every 10 seconds.

```
while(index<retryCount)
    {
        string toSend = wstring_to_utf8(sRequestData);
        nRet = send(sockfd, toSend.c_str(), toSend.length(), 0);
        if (nRet == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            wsaErr = WSAGetLastError();
            Sleep(DEFAULT);
            index++;
        }
        else if(nRet == toSend.length())
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            index = 0;
        }
    }
```

The problem here is, after some hours of send and receive from C++ to Java server , the send gets hanged for infinite time. The execution never comes out from the send() function. But after the hang if i abruptly close the Java server , then the send returns socket error and again works well for some hours and the hang still occurs.

As i mentioned i keep on sending data to server of size varied from 1 MB to 3 MB ten seconds once. What could be the issue here? How can i sort this out?

Comment: Your Java `getDataFromSocket` method needs a lot of work. `is.available()` is not a sensible way to determine a message boundary. If you just want to read until EOF you could do it in a few lines of Java code and do it correctly.

Comment: @JamesKPolk - Getting the is.available() just to new the charbuffer and to give that as a argument to read() function.